# How to add position=position_jitter() to the geom_point() layer of an existing ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently found out that one can use syntax like `p$layers[[1]]$aes_params$color <- "red"` to change aesthetic parameters of ggplot objects. However, when I try to set `position=position_jitter()` on a `geom_point()` layer this doesn't seem to do anything. What do I need to do to make this work?

Below is a simple example.

```
library(ggplot2)

p_original <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + labs(title="Original")
p_jittered <- p_original + labs(title="Jittered")
p_jittered$layers[[1]]$aes_params$position <- position_jitter(10,10)

p_original
p_jittered
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just because one can use `p$layers[[1]]$aes_params$color <- "red"`, doesn't mean you should. It makes your code less readable and you're messing with the internals that ggplot2 doesn't advertise as modification points. Lastly, a position adjustment is not an aesthetic, so that is why that doesn't work here.

Comment: You're right that's probably not advisable and I normally wouldn't change the aesthetics this way as it is much easier to supply `position=position_jitter()` in the code that creates the plot. However, I happen to have a lot of plot objects that I need to modify and I can't easily change the original code that creates them. After some more testing I found that I can set it through `p$layers[[1]]$position <- position_jitter()`! As a side note: if interacting with internals like this is ill-advised, what's better solution to modifying gg objects after they've been created?

Comment: @degeso: if your solution worked, please consider posting it as an answer and accepting it (for future reference and to mark the question as resolved). Also, making the title even more specific, like "Change position argument of existing ggplot layer" will help future users to find your solution.

Answer (score 1):

{[gginnards](https://docs.r4photobiology.info/gginnards/index.html)} eases post-hoc manipulation, e. g. of layers.

Example:

```
library(gginnards)

p <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))

## find the ids of point layers:
which_layers(p_original, 'GeomPoint')
## > [1] 1

## there's only one point layer, so pick this first item without bothering with further identification:

lyr <- extract_layers(p_original, idx = 1)[[1]]

## change position:
lyr$position <- position_jitter()

## remove original layer and add changed one:
p |>
  delete_layers(idx = 1) |>
  append_layers(lyr)
```